# imap_decode issue with base64

Tags: php, imap

I have the following code to extract only the message of the email on my custom ticket system.

```
$explotar_mensaje=explode('<!--PLANTILLA_CORREO_THMX-->',$message_original);
        if(base64_encode(base64_decode($explotar_mensaje[0], true)) === $explotar_mensaje[0]){
            //$message=htmlentities($explotar_mensaje[0], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
            $message=base64_decode($explotar_mensaje[0]);
        }else{
            $message = quoted_printable_decode($explotar_mensaje[0]);
        }
```

Email with quote-printables headers are passed successful but with base64 I get as the following:

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8" Content-Transfer-Encoding:
> base64
>
> QnVlbmFzIHRhcmRlcy4NCg0KRW52aW8gbGEgZmljaGEgZGUgcGFnbywgZmF2b3IgZGUgYXBveWFy
> bm9zIGNvbiBsYSBmYWN0dXJhIHRpbWJyYWRhLg0KDQpTYWx1ZG9zDQoNCltjaWQ6aW1hZ2UwMDEu
> cG5nQDAxRDg2Mzk4LjE0RUMyOUYwXQ0KDQpEZTogUGFnb3MgeSBGYWN0dXJhY2nDs24gdHVIT1NU
> Lm14IDxwYWdvc0B0dWhvc3QubXg+DQpFbnZpYWRvIGVsOiBqdWV2ZXMsIDI4IGRlIGFicmlsIGRl
> IDIwMjIgMDQ6MDAgcC4gbS4NClBhcmE6IENFTFNPIENBUlJBU0NPIFBFUkVaIDxlbmFfY2FyckBo
> b3RtYWlsLmNvbT4NCkFzdW50bzogRmFjdHVyYSAjMjg5NCBQZW5kaWVudGUgZGUgUGFnbw0KDQpO

Any clue?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the question here? It’s unclear what you expect to happen, but by simply echoing values and seeing what they look like you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Like @miken32 said, it's unclear what you're looking for. What are you echoing that gives you that base64 encoded value? Why can't you just `base64_decode()` it?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I need to decode a base64 message instead of get an unreadable message.